# How can I restore my desktop

Tags: 20.04, ubuntu-mate

I am not sure what I did or what is is called, but I no longer have that bar on the bottom of my screen.

https://imgur.com/a/3fF6DYb

Can someone help me restore it ?

Comment: Please provide additional information like the OS, kernel version, etc.

Comment: Including also the desktop environment you use and the customizations you did: your system seems heavily customized, and on stock Ubuntu, there is no bar on the bottom of the screen, so we are not in a position currently to know what you are talking about.

Comment: does [this post](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/lost-my-taskbar/19183) help?

Comment: @graham The post led me to the answer. I created a new panel positioned on the bottom of my screen. I then right clicked the panel and clicked on "reset all panels". It lost all my customizations but now when I minimize an app, it shows up on the bottom panel.

Comment: you should post that as an answer which may help someone else with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new panel positioned on the bottom of my screen.

I then right clicked the panel and clicked on "reset all panels".

It loses any customization's but now when I minimize an app, it shows up on the bottom panel.